# Phonegap - Android - should I be wary about using an Iframe?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have built an Android App using Phonegap/HTML5/JQuery mobile.  I had the option of parsing XML data or simply IFraming a server page to display some particular content - the Iframed version seems to work faster and without issue in the 3 test phones I have - I'm just concerned I've missed something - are there any big disadvantages of using IFrames in this situation?

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Can you trust the XML content? (I'd always say no: **never trust your input**). In which case, are you blindly writing this XML to an iframe? If so, it sounds insecure.

If I were in your situation I'd ask myself the following before resorting to the iframe solution:

- Why is parsing it slower? Have you investigated that?
- What about using a lighter data format like JSON or AIML or just CSV?
- What am I using this XML data for? Is it required?
- What similar applications are there that I think do what I do and how do they work?